# search contract - constraining within an app and using from outside search charm

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

Two questions about search contract.

1. Is there anyway of constraining the search within an app?
2. Also I know how can I use search contract from inside a charm. Is there anyway this contract be used outside of search charm?

Answer (score 0):

you can [section 2.1 add filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465238.aspx) to your search page to allow user to refine the query.

you can programmatically invoke to [show the search pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.search.searchpane.show.aspx) if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to describe the context of the you're trying to implement, but I'll take a stab at these.

1. You're writing the 'search code' that fires on the [onactivated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212679.aspx), so you can constrain the search however you want to.  The [Search contract sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Search-app-contract-sample-118a92f5) on dev.windows.com handles a number of scenarios that may be applicable in your case.
2. No, the other party in the contract is Windows 8 (surfaced through the search charm). But you could add your own in-app search capabilities if needed.

I've found the [Guidelines and Checklist for Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx) to be a good read and it provided a lot of insight to user experience concerns and tradeoffs that weren't immediately obvious to me.